# What is the data inside AudioData? (OpenAI Whisper)

Tags: python, openai-api, openai-whisper

I am trying to understand what the output of `audio2` is. When I print it, all I get is its location. However, I would like to know specifically what type of data is located inside `audio2` and what type of input is required for the `recognize_google()` function

```py
import speech_recognition as sr
import pyttsx3
import whisper

model = whisper.load_model("base")
r = sr.Recognizer()

audio2 = r.listen(source2)

result = r.recognize_google(audio2)
```

I tried printing `audio2` but I don't get any bits or any information on the wav file.

Comment: Isn't that ```listen()``` a SpeechRecognition API? See [this](https://github.com/Uberi/speech_recognition/blob/master/reference/library-reference.rst#audiodataframe_data-bytes-sample_rate-int-sample_width-int---audiodata). A useful tip - ```help(audio2)```.

Comment: I managed to make the AudioData into a byte instance but I am back no trouble making that into a string.

Comment: What do you mean? Anyway if you solved the problem, why not answer your own question?

Comment: I did not answer the problem. I need to make the byte instance into a string. Hopefully, that clarifies the question.

Comment: What form of the string do you expect? You mean something like ```print(audio2.frame_data)```?

Comment: That code makes the data into a byte class. I need to convert that data into a string type.

Comment: Should I do twenty questions? Why not describe what you want exactly? Anyway one more guess, ```import numpy as np; print(np.frombuffer(audio2.get_raw_data(convert_width=2), 'int16'))```?